# Response is sent before all events are processed in nodejs express module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am experiencing an issue with express module in node js. Problem statement is response is sent before all events are completed.

In below code, I am calling the function 'commonValidations()' when client hits the respective URI. Inside commonValidations() function, some other functions are invoked internally. But the response is being sent before all validations are completed.

I tried with  `res.on('end', callbackfunction)` then I got some errors with this statement, then I put `res.end()` function. But still res is sent before all events are completed.

Can someone help me on how I can send the response after all events are processed?

-->app.js (I didn't put the db connection string and connection pool details)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var path = require('path');
var http = require("http");
var app = express();

var DB2Pool = require('ibm_db').Pool;
GLOBAL.gCNPool = new DB2Pool();
GLOBAL.gCNString;

GLOBAL.gErrors = {
  "teslaRequest":{type : Object},
   "error":[]
}; 
http.createServer(app).listen(3030);
GLOBAL.directoryName=path.resolve(__dirname);
var common = require(directoryName+'/validations/common.js');

app.post("/cfo/taxprofile/stateprofiles/validate", function(req, res){
   gCNPool.open(gCNString, function(err, db){
      common.commonValidations(db);
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
      res.end(JSON.stringify(gErrors));
   }

});
```

Before stateAbbrValidation function completes, response is sent to the client.

--> common.js

```
var query = require(directoryName+'/utils/sql_queries.js');
var app = require(directoryName+'/app.js');

module.exports = {
        commonValidations:function(db){
            stateAbbrValidation(db);
        }
};

function stateAbbrValidation(db){
    console.log('Query is '+STATE_S01_1);

    if(gStateAbbr == null || gStateAbbr == 'undefined')
        gErrors.error.push({"errorCode":"E062", "errorDesc":"Invalid State code"});
    else{
        db.query(STATE_S01_1.replace('<STATE>', gStateAbbr), function(err1, rows){
            if(err1){
                console.log(err1);
            }
            if(Object.keys(rows).length == 0){
                console.log('Result size '+Object.keys(rows).length);
                gErrors.error.push({"errorCode":"E062", "errorDesc":"Invalid State code"});
            }
            else{
                if(gStateCodeValue != null || gStateCodeValue != 'undefined'){
                    var cdKeys = Object.keys(rows);
                    var stateCd = rows[cdKeys[0]].STATE_CODE;
                    if(stateCd != gStateCodeValue){
                        gErrors.error.push({"errorCode":"E062", "errorDesc":"Invalid State code"});
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*db.prepare(STATE_S01_1, function(err, stmt){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        stmt.execute(['CA'], function(err, result, rows){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(result);
            result.closeSync();
            console.log(result);
            console.log(rows);
        });
    });*/
}
```

Comment: Why don't you share the relevant code? The part you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). It helps in sending a response after all events are processed.
See the following example taken from [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) :

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});


// an example using an object instead of an array
async.series({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```

Note: Every function should have a callback and in the end the collective result of all callbacks is sent as an array.

Comment: Thanks Naitik. I tried with series function in async module, this time call is not going to second task. var asyncTasks = [];
    asyncTasks.push(function(){
     console.log('testing');
     common.commonValidations(db);
    });
      asyncTasks.push(function(){
     gErrors.teslaRequest = gReqBody;
     console.log('testing2');
     res.send(JSON.stringify(gErrors));
    });
  
    async.series(asyncTasks, function(err, results){
     console.log('error is '+err);
     console.log(results);
    });